# Google Cloud Import Statement not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech

I am a newbie & trying to convert speech to text. For this, I am trying to write a piece of code in Python 3.9/ PyCharm Community Edition.

I try writing this statement (from google.cloud import speech). However it does not recognize google.cloud. It says "Unresolved reference google".

I did install "google.cloud" using the command "pip install google-cloud". However no success.

Any idea how to do I solve this issue?

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Use `import google-cloud-speech`. The package `google-cloud` is deprecated as of June 18, 2018 and should not be used. Here is a link to the supported Python packages: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python#google-cloud-python-client

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry. Typo: `import google.cloud.speech`. You will need to install the package first: `pip install google-cloud-speech`.

Comment: Doesn't work still. The google in (import google.cloud.speech) shows a red underline.

Comment: Python is fairly good with its error messages. Edit your question with the results of `pip freeze`, python version and the error messages.

Comment: From the update you posted in the the deleted answer, you still have google-cloud installed. You need to uninstall that package and then install the correct package.

Comment: Same error!....

Comment: Please follow this [Quick-start](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python)  and let us know how it works, additional please add in your question a code snippet of your  implementation to get more context of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

Reading the suggestions above, I solved installing the google-cloud-storage package in PyCharm (that installed a lot of dependent packages).
Then I changed that import in

```
from google.cloud.storage import client
```

Client was the class I needed.

Davide